# How to correctly design urls for pages and data

Tags: python, ajax, rest, flask

In a web app I am working on (Flask), I have routes that render html and, for the client-side JS app for that page, routes that return json data.

I am having trouble designing the urls for such scenarios. For example, if I click on a model of a car (the app is about cars) I need to render the page that displays model details, but at the same time I need to get the data for the model and all its different variants as well. So far, I have:

```
@app.route("/model/<oid>")
def model_page(oid):
    return render_template('model-details.html')
```

I render this page and then get the `oid` in my JS application on the client side. Then I make an ajax call to another method such as

```
@app.route("/model/details/<oid>")
def model_details(oid):
    m = get_model(oid)
    return json.dumps({'model': m})
```

I feel am doing this wrong because essentially the first method should return the data I want (following REST principles). If I did that, my page url will mess up (it is important for me to have a good url for the page to let my users go to it directly).

How do I cleanly separate page rendering urls from 'data-returning' urls?

Answer (score 0):

Not a flask expert, but I would imagine you can pass in a variable into your template containing the model details. Doing this would get rid of the need for a second call entirely. Can your controller fetch the details info somehow and pass it in like so?

```
@app.route("/model/<oid>")
def model_page(oid):
    m = get_model(oid)
    return render_template('model-details.html', model=m)
```

You might have to send over your model as json, but this pattern should work for this case.

Comment: True. But that's not what I want to do. I want to interact with the data through my JS application.

Comment: In that case, your pattern of a separate AJAX call works fine - I would think you would want to render the template with some data loaded to save another server call, though.